# Corona SDK, LUA: rotation and motion groups and display objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a problem (obviously). Actually I don't know why this solution doesnt work.

I have background which is moving on every frame rate. I have also 2 buttons on screen. When I push and hold left button background rotate to left, when right - background rotate to right. In point (1) I'm making some calculation how this background should move in current frame. Later I assign result of this calculation in point (2). Everything works fine -- lets call it situation A.

Now I want to add group of some objects which will be move in the same direction as background..and here appear problem. When I add in point (3) eventListener to this group (called myGroup), background and myGroup are moving in different way than background alone (from situation A).

Here are my questions:

1. Can I put group into another group?
2. Can I add event listener into group?

or any other idea why after adding listener into myGroup, background and myGroup don't move as backround alone (without myGroup with listener)?

I hope I explained my problem clearly. Thx in advance for help!

```
function createGame()

    background = display.newImage("background.jpg", 0, 0, true);
    background.x = _W/2; background.y = _H/2;       
    background.enterFrame = onFrame;
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", background);
    group:insert(background);

    myGroup = display.newGroup();
    myGroup.xReference = _W/2; myGroup.yReference = _H/2;
    myGroup.enterFrame = onFrame;
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", myGroup); -- (3)
    group:insert(myGroup); -- this group called "group" comes from storyboard

    myGroup:insert(some other objects);
end

-- Move background:
function onFrame(self)

    -- (1) Calculate next move of background:
    -- (I'm making some calculation here how background should move. Calculation returns X and Y)

    -- (2) Move background and group:
    self.y = self.y + Y; 
    self.x = self.x + X;
    self.yReference = self.yReference - Y;
    self.xReference = self.xReference - X;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. Actually it is bad idea to put 2 different runtime listeners into 2 different groups. This attitude caused a problem. It should looks like below:

```
function createGame()

    gameGroup = display.newGroup();
    gameGroup.xReference = _W/2; myGroup.yReference = _H/2;
    gameGroup.enterFrame = onFrame;
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", gameGroup);
    group:insert(myGroup); -- this group called "group" comes from storyboard

    background = display.newImage("background.jpg", 0, 0, true);
    background.x = _W/2; background.y = _H/2;       
    gameGroup:insert(background);

    myGroup = display.newGroup();
    myGroup:insert(some other objects);
    gameGroup:insert(myGroup);  

end
```

and now works like a charm!

Thanks krs and DevfaR for answers and hints :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes you can put group to another group just like this

   ```
   local group1 = display.newGroup()
   local group2 = display.newGroup()
   group2:insert(group1);
   ```
2. Yes you can put event Listener to group

   ```
   group2:addEventListener("touch", function)
   ```

are you using physics to rotate your object?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if I'm using physics or not. Turning on/off physics doesn't change rotation/motion behaviour. Moreover I discovered that if myGroup is empty (just declared) problem still occur.

Comment: does the answer you've ask solve the question? it's quite difficult to understand what you really want to achieve :)

Comment: My answer above doesnt solve problem. I want to understand how its possible that display group with event listener changes motion of my background..It makes me confused @.@

Comment: can you provide further more codes to see where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

here you are using

```
self.x = self.x + X;
```

Just declare the `background` and `myGroup` outside your `createGame` function(this will give those objects a global posibility in the particular class) as below:

```
local background
local myGroup
```

and then you can move them inside the function as:

```
background.x = background.x + X;
or
myGroup.x = myGroup.x + X;             
--[[ instead of moving self. ]]--
```

Keep coding............... :)

Comment: Actually I have declared backgroumd and myGroup outside createGame function. I just didn't write it in code above. By the way what is difference between self.x = self.x + X and background.x = background.x + X, when I add background as listener? Mean it that "self" isn't equal to any of objects with listener? (in range of specified function ofc). Thx for answer krs, but my problem is still unsolved :-(

Comment: Ok, as DevfaR said, can you provide further more codes to see where the exact problem is?